# Не перерисовывается компонент после обновления глобального стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-native

Простое приложение агрегатор новостей через api newsapi с возможностью подписаться на журнал и видеть новости в ленте.

Есть два экрана: первый - лента новостей, второй - список журналов с кнопкой подписки. При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает action и обновляет в state объект со списком журналов. Все обновляется, данные приходят, но компонент не перерисовывается, ни экран с лентой новостей, ни кнопка не изменяется (должна меняться иконка).

**Компонент вывода списка журналов**

```js
class JournalList extends PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: (
      <HeaderBack navigation={navigation} />
    )
  });

  state = {
    journals: [],
    loading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getJournals();
  };

  getJournals = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // prettier-ignore
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?country=${navigation.state.params.country}&apiKey=${apiKey["api"]}`;
    let journalResp = await fetch(url);
    let journalData = await journalResp.json();

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      journals: journalData.sources
    });
  };

  toggleSubToJournal = (name, id) => {
    this.props.journalSubscriptions[name] ?
      this.props.unsubscribeToJournal(name, id) :
      this.props.subscribeToJournal(name, id)
  };

  renderRow = journal => {
    const { journalSubscriptions } = this.props;
    return (
      <RowCard
        text={journal.item.name}
        iconName={
          journalSubscriptions[journal.item.name] ? "heart" : "heart-outlined" // Здесь должна меняться иконка
        }
        onPress={() => this.openModal(journal.item.name, journal.item.description)}
        onPressIcon={() => this.toggleSubToJournal(journal.item.name, journal.item.id)}
      />
    );
  };

  renderResults = () => {
    const { journals } = this.state;
    return (
        <FlatList 
          data={journals}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? <DefaultLoader /> : this.renderResults();
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    journalSubscriptions: state.journalSubscriptions
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(JournalList);
```

**Action**

```
const subscribeToJournal = ( journalName, journalID) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let database = firebase.database();

    let userResponse = await database.ref("/" + userID);
    let userFollowResponse = await userResponse.once("value");
    let userFollowData = await userFollowResponse.val();

    if (userFollowData && userFollowData[journalName]) {
      console.log(userFollowData)
    } else {
      let resultData = {
        ...userFollowData,
        [journalName]: journalID
      }

      // prettier-ignore
      await database.ref("/" + userID).set(resultData, () => dispatch(setJournalSubscriptions( resultData )));
    }
  };
};

const setJournalSubscriptions = journalSubscriptions => ({
  type: types.JOURNAL_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
  payload: journalSubscriptions
});

export {
  subscribeToJournal,
  setJournalSubscriptions
};
```

Все срабатывает, глобальный state меняется, но компонент не перерисовывается (не меняется иконка). render вызывается с уже обновленными данными, я проверял.

У меня предположение, что я неправильно прокидываю данные в props, в компонент RowCards

Comment: Попробуйте в connect 3им параметром передать объект - {pure: false}

Comment: Выпала ошибка: Invalid value of type object for mergeProps argument when connecting component JournalList. Если передать этот объект 4-м аргументом, а 3-м null, ошибки нет. Но это не помогает решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй добавить к `<Image>` key, и присвоить ему значение которое передается в `scr`.